# How can I have an array of structure inside a structure?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Let's say I have a structure called "Film" and a structure called "Actor"

```
typedef struct actor{
    char *Name;
    char *Surname;
    int year_birth;
    Title_Film * Film_recited;
}Actor;


typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    //array of "Actor" structure
}Film;
```

I want to insert an array of structure "Actor" inside the structure "Film" because in a film there are a lot of actors. Can I do it ?How?

Comment: Just swap the definitions around, and define an array member within `struct film`.

Comment: You know in general arrays come with fixed size, right? So what's stopping you?

Comment: I am a bit fay about the `Title_Film *` member in both of the structs. In the case of `struct film` I can see that might supposed to be the *film title* but in the case of `struct actor` it could be an *array of films* in which the actor appears. Yet the declarations are the same, and not posted.

Comment: Yes you are right the 'film title' in 'Actor' should be also an array.My fault.
It was the first time i encountered an array of structures so i was a bit confused but now i understood.

Comment: There is no array in the declarations. A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define an actor before you define the film, or else the compiler won't know how to handle it.

In the film struct, simply declare the pointer as I have shown you below.

```
typedef struct actor{
    char *Name;
    char *Surname;
    int year_birth;
    Title_Film * Film_recited;
}Actor;


typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    //array of "Actor" structure
    Actor* cast;
}Film;
```

Once you have your pointer, you will need to figure out how many actors you will have.  You could prompt for this or hard code it into your program if you have a specific instance in mind.  Whatever floats your boat.

now that you know how large your cast is (let's say you saved it as an integer in variable castSize, allocate the memory:

```
movie.cast = (Actor*)malloc(sizeof(Actor)*castSize);
```

you can now access the list of actors like an array, which will give you access to their attributes.  For example:

```
movie.cast[0]->Name = "Scarlet";
movie.cast[0]->Surname = "Johansson";
movie.cast[0].year_birth = 1984;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know how many array elements you need ahead of time, you'd do it like this:

```
typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    Actor *actor_list;
}Film;
```

Here, `actor_list` is a pointer which can be made to point to a dynamically allocated array of `Actor` objects.  You can allocate the space for as many as you need at the time as follows:

```
Film myfilm;
...
myfilm.actor_list = malloc(num_of_actors * sizeof(Actor));
```

If on the other hand you *do* know how many you need at compile time, you just declare the array member directly:

```
#define ACTOR_LEN 20

typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    Actor actor_list[ACTOR_LEN];
}Film;
```

Comment: and you claim `actor_list` to be an array?

Comment: `Assuming you know know how many you need ahead of time`...Q.why do I need to know? A: arrays. Q: Otherwise? A: Pointer and dynamic allocation. (_Please add this_)

Answer (score 0):

You can either insert array of actors into film structure

```
#define ACTORS_MAX_N 10
struct film {
    /* ... */
    struct actor arr[ACTORS_MAX_N];
};
```

or you can keep a pointer in that structure to memory containing actors:

```
struct film {
    /* ... */
    struct actor *arr;
};
```

As you can see, in first case (of built-in array) you have to know the size of this array in advance. In second case (of pointer) you get the flexibility of dynamic array allocation/free/reallocation, so the same `film` object can reference arrays of different size.

---

In C-99 standard there is also possibility to store flexible array, that is array that will be allocated dynamically, so it can have different sizes:

```
struct film {
    /* ... */
    size_t actors_n;
    struct actor arr[]; /* flexible array MUST be last member in struct */
};
```

The sizeof operator will return the offset of flexible array, so you can allocate it this way:

```
struct film *allocate_film(size_t actors_n) {
    struct film *film = malloc(sizeof *film + actors_n * sizeof(film->arr[0]));
    if (film == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    film->actors_n = actors_n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < actors_n; ++i) {
        film->arr[i].Name = /* ...  */
        /* ... allocate actor */
    }
    return film;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any type `T`, you can have an array of `T` in one of two ways:

- As an array object: `T arr[N];`
- As a pointer to `T`, for which you dynamically allocate memory: `T *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );`

So, within your `Film` type, you can do either:

```
typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    Actor cast[N]; // where N is known at compile time
}Film;
```

or

```
typedef struct film{
    Title_Film * Title; //pointer to structure 
    int year;
    type genre; //enum
    director * director_Film; //pointer to structure
    Actor *cast;
}Film;
```

In the first case, you only need to create the `Film` instance in order for the `cast` array to be created as well:

```
Film jaws;
jaws.cast[0].name = strdup( "Roy" );         // assumes strdup is available
jaws.cast[0].surname = strdup( "Scheider" ); // otherwise you'll have to use
jaws.cast[1].name = strdup( "Richard" );     // a combination of malloc and
jaws.cast[1].surname = strdup( "Dreyfuss" ); // strcpy
```

etc.

In the second case, there's an additional step necessary to allocate the memory for the `cast` array:

```
Film jaws2;
jaws2.cast = malloc( sizeof *jaws2.cast * cast_size );

jaws2.cast[0].name = strdup( "Roy" );
jaws2.cast[0].surname = strdup( "Scheider" );
```

etc.

In both cases, you'll need to `free` each `cast[i].name` and `cast[i].surname` when you're done with it.  In the second case, you'll also need to `free` the `cast` member itself (every `malloc/calloc` should have a corresponding `free` somewhere).

Since cast sizes vary between films, the second method is preferable as it can be sized as necessary for each film.  Also, it allows you to *resize* the array with `realloc` if you need to extend it later.  An even better solution would be to use a linked list or similar container that can grow and shrink as necessary, but that's a *bit* more work.

It's not clear why you need the `Title_Film` member in the `Actors` type; since the actor is being associated with the film, the title is already there.

To be honest, the right way to model a many-to-many relationship (films have multiple actors, actors appear in multiple films) is for `Film` *not* to contain an array of `Actor` or vice-versa; instead, you should have separate `Film` and `Actor` arrays (or lists, or trees, whatever), and create an *additional* array (or list, or tree, whatever) of a type that associates individual `Actor` entries to `Film` entries:

```
struct assoc {
   Actor *actor;
   Film *film;
} ActorFilmAssoc;

Actor *findActor( Actor *list, const char *surname, const char *name ) { ... }
Film *findFilm( Film *list, const char *title ) { ... }

Actor *actors = calloc( num_actors, sizeof *actors );
Film  *films  = calloc( num_films, sizeof *films );

/**
 * Add entries to actors and films
 */

ActorFilmAssoc *map = calloc( someSize, sizeof *map );
size_t entry = 0;
...
map[++entry].actor = findActor( actors, "Scheider", "Roy" );
map[entry].film = findFilm( films, "Jaws" );
map[++entry].actor = findActor( actors, "Scheider", "Roy" );
map[entry].film = findFilm( films, "All That Jazz" );
```

Instead of storing multiple `Actor` entries for Roy Scheider with each film, we store a single entry in the `actors` array, and just have multiple pointers to it in `map`.

This is a *very* simplistic example; you *will* want to use something more sophisticated than a linear array for your map.  But it should illustrate the concept.